# How do I generate a primary key that is not random?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, data-annotations

I want to be able to set the value of my primary key to an auto increment number. At the moment it generates a random key such as 13917c50-6b8c-4405-82ce...

I want to be able to tell the system "Hey, I want request number to start at 1 (or 1000 or whatever) and auto increment every time a record is saved."

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public string request_no { get; set; }
```

I expect, as a record is saved, for a request number of my choosing to be auto generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DatabaseGenerated` attribute:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int request_no { get; set; }
}
```

Also if you want to create seed for `request_no` then you should use custom database initializer and execute `DBCC CHECKIDENT` query:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Request', RESEED, 1000)
```